# Need the mail to be triggered upon success or failure of Build or release definition in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I have a requirement like whenever my build or release definition fails in VSTS it should trigger mails to all the team members including the error part.How can it possible? Please share your thoughts on this.As I don't see any information available from Google.if build fails, mail with subject "build failed" and body containing which step in definition failed and its explanation,stylecop errors,
Code analysis error,
test fails,
codecoverage results,
or simply build error.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTS has a build-in feature ([Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/manage-team-notifications)) of sending email to corresponding users when build complete or fail, but you can’t custom the email body.

You need to use a power-shell script to get status of all the tasks in build definition. This script query the status from Apis available in VSTS.
 And then use the result to prepare a custom email body and sending out this mail through a third party email sender.

There is the sample of build result: [build-results-enhancer](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer) . For how to send email in a build/release pipeline you could take a look at this blog: [Sending Email Notification from VSTS/TFS Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/19/sending-email-notification-from-vststfs-build/)

Comment: I have found in Notifications tab in VSTS.thanks much.I will accept this as answer.